# Move web browser view on button click

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a web browser and i have created four buttons:
Up, Down, Left, Right. The web browser contains a realtive html file "map.html". The view can be increased by clicking + or decrease by clicking -. If the user clicks + the map will extend and the user might want to move to the left etc.

Now to my buttons when the user clicks on the left button the web browser shall move 10 pixels to the left but I dont really know how to that.

```
private void leftBtn_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Point position = e.GetPosition(webBrowser1);

            double pX = position.X;
            double pY = position.Y;

        }
```

This is how I´ve started how can i get the web browser to move 10 pixels on each click?

Comment: Does the map in the WebBrowserControl not support drag and pinch/stretch gestures to move and zoom? If so I suspect most users will use that rather than tapping any controls you add on top.

Comment: Well the map are in html and javascript and I have done it with the leaflet framework and that framework does not support windows phone 7, so for now this is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Position your `WebBrowser` control within a `Canvas`, this panel allows you to specify a controls location via x / y coordinates:

```
<Canvas>
  <WebBrowser x:Name="browser"/>
</Canvas>
```

You can now move your browser by setting its top / left location. For example:

```
Canvas.SetTop(browser, 10.0);
Canvas.SetLeft(browser, 10.0);
```

This will move your control.

Comment: I can´t really get that to work. The code with the "Canvas" shall be created i the .xaml file and the Canvas.Set.. in the .cs file? But that does not work..

Comment: I'm not surprised this doesn't work - the WebBrowserControl is special in that it does its own virtualization and scrolling internally, but appears to be a fixed size to Silverlight. I'm guessing this XAML would lead to the layout engine having trouble figuring out what size to display the WBC (I haven't tried though).

Comment: @PaulAnnetts True, the WebBrowser control is 'special', it contains a TileHost which is a native component for rendering web pages. However, the WebBrowser itself still adheres to the Silverlight layout rules, and as such you get set its location via a Canvas.

Comment: Indeed the WebBrowser itself still adheres to the Silverlight layout rules, but how can i acess this in the .cs file? So when the user presses a button I can set the new positions?

Comment: @user1151471 The x:Name in the above XAML ensures that the generated code-behind file includes a field named 'browser' which references this control.

Comment: @ColinE Ok it worked fine, but now I realized one other problem, the entire browser moves but I just want the content to move. hmmmm...